# RaspberryPi Snappy Ubuntu. Screen only flashes on and of on boot

Tags: raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

I've tried to follow the insturctions as best I can to make this work.
When I plug the Raspberry in and boot it up, the screens shows first a window of colors for 1 or 2 seconds, next it shows a black screen with the Raspberry icon in the top left corner, and then the screen blacks out and then it starts over, doing the same thing again and again and again.

I believe I have the required model.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I just posted [the same question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/587129/snappy-on-raspberry-pi-2-failing-to-boot) a few hours before ;)

Answer (score 1):

By the description, it sounds like you're using a Raspberry Pi B or B+, which has an ARMv6 CPU. To use Snappy, you need a Raspberry Pi 2, which has an ARMv7 CPU.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/587129/snappy-on-raspberry-pi-2-failing-to-boot