# Snappy on Raspberry Pi 2 failing to boot

Tags: boot, raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

I've just got brand new Raspberry Pi 2 model B, and tried to install [Snappy Ubuntu Core alpha-02](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) on a brand new Samsung EVO 16 GB micro SD card.

When I boot the Pi, I don't see it appear on the network (checking my DHCP allocations on my router). The Ethernet LEDs of the Pi are both on and I checked the cable.

When I boot the Pi connected to an HDMI screeen, there is a black screen with 4 Rapberry logos on the upper left of the screen, and it stays like that forever.

What could have gone wrong?

Comment: @Fabby: Snappy is an official build of Ubuntu launched by Mark Shuttleworth. See http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/ and http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1434

Comment: My bad! (I learned something today...)  Will warn others too!  Thanks for the info.  Close vote retracted.

Comment: (and called someone in that has a PI 2)

Comment: @dolmen Have you made sure SHA-1-sum of the IMG you downloaded is the same as the one listed on the Raspberry Pi download page? I was able to flash & boot Snappy Core on my Pi 2 just fine with my 4GB DANE-ELEC MicroSD car. If it's not the IMG file, it could be the SD card - the 8 & 32 GB versions of the Samsung EVO 16GB MicroSD card are both listed as `not ok` on the [RPi SD cards eLinux page](http://elinux.org/RPi_SD_cards) - try a different card if you have it.

Comment: still being close voted :/ dolmen can you find any text useful for debugging shown upon boot? (you sometimes have to press a key or something). How did you flash the SD card?

Answer (score 2):

Power supply is at fault you need 2Amps for a pi 2 which is why you get the colored screen